# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline environment block variables inside email template

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass some variables to an email template after build. I use environment blocks for that (some of them also are created in scripts). 
Is this possible?

```
environment {
    SUBSCRIPTION = credentials('subscription')
    CERT = credentials('cert')  
}

post {
    always {
        emailext attachLog: true, 
            body: '''${SCRIPT,template="email.template"}''', 
            compressLog: true, 
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            subject: "SUCCESS: ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]",
            to: 'email@email.com'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made workaround for that, in post step I trigger another job with all data that I need (pass as params) than inside scripted email template I can use them